# How to check if a string contains an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to write a function that accepts a string and returns a boolean value based on whether or not that string contains an array (syntax).

And I need help with the regex pattern.

Here's an example of a string that would return `true`:

```
'["Visual Thinking", "GitHub", "Any"]'
```

Here's an example of a string that would return `false`:

```
"This string does not contain array syntax"
```

Until now you have been developing the following pattern

```
/\[((\"\w*\")(,)?)*\]/g
```

Comment: In the general case, doing this with a regular expression would be somewhere between hard and impossible. What about `'["String 1]", "[String 2"]'`?

Comment: Try to JSON-parse it and if that results in an array, return true? Trying to replicate a regex which matches any and all possible valid array syntaxes and futile.

Comment: This also largely depends on what you would consider valid notation for the array. If your strings fit JSONs that's all fine but if you need broader syntax rules then you would need to write your own parser or even use `eval` if you are going for the full grammar of javascript array literals.

Comment: There are AST parsers for JavaScript that you might also consider e.g. acorn.

Comment: @Minus Even trying to produce a regex that is valid for all possible JSON arrays is futile. Arrays can contain nested arrays and objects and strings and other stuff, and you'll need to consider escaping rules and all the rest…

Comment: @deceze Right, that's why I suggested writing a parser (if he truly needs that). I'm not saying he should parse the string with a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect whether string is an array or not using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```js
const str = '["Visual Thinking", "GitHub", "Any"]';
let isArr;

try {
  const arr = JSON.parse(str);
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) isArr = true;
} catch (error) {
  isArr = false;
}

console.log(isArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

this is my approach for solving this problem.

if you want to capture the array or arrays you can expend upon that.

```
let string = 'pape saliou is a good ["Visual Thinking", "GitHub", "Any"]';


function checkArrayInString(){
  let strArr = string.split('');

  let brackets = {
   '[':'left',
   ']':'right'
  };

  let leftBrackets=[];
  let rightBrackets=[];
  for(let i=0; i<strArr.length; i++){
    if(brackets[strArr[i]] ==='left'){
      leftBrackets.push(i);
    }
    if(brackets[strArr[i]]==='right'){
      rightBrackets.push(i);
    }
  }
  
return leftBrackets[0]<rightBrackets[0]
}

checkArrayInString(string);
```

this will check if there is at least one array in the string;

Answer (score -3):

Another solution is to just use the [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function, and after that check is that an array or not, without converting that to the array. Like this:

```js
const checkArray = (text) => {
  try {
    let res = eval(text);
    return Array.isArray(res);
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}

let wrongText = '[AAAAA"Visual Thinking", "GitHub", "Any"]';
console.log(checkArray(wrongText)); // false
let rightText = '["Visual Thinking", "GitHub", "Any"]';
console.log(checkArray(rightText)); // true
```

Comment: Using `JSON.parse` instead of `eval` is less risky because, unlike the latter, it doesn't allow arbitrary code execution (I did not downvote)

Comment: Maybe OK if you completely trust the source of the to-be-evaluated text, but otherwise inadvisable.

Comment: I did downvote. Eval is both dangerous and inefficient for this.

Comment: Don't use this snippet because eval() it's very dangerous.

Comment: ok guys.. I don't care about voting.. actually I know that eval() not often used nowadays,  but please just refer some example: how it can be dangerous for attackers, when all the stuff works on the client side, and back-end validates all the incoming requests?

Comment: Assume that I'm not agree with you, so please proove me you can do some dangerous stuff with that eval().. thanks